# Random Error While using Casperjs with exec on PHP page

Tags: php, node.js, centos, phantomjs, casperjs

Hi I wrote a script in Casperjs to retrieve some infos from HTML of some interesting sites.

My Environment is:
- Centos 7, with nginx installed, Php 7, Php-fpm, nodejs & npm (both of them latest version).

Sometimes, absolutely randomly, I catch an error when I launch the script through php page with exec command or shell_exec command.

The string is like

/usr/bin/casperjs /path/to/file/casperscript.js --param1=p1 --param2=p2

and so on. Obviously at end of command i put 2>&1 to catch the following error:

```
events.js:160 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error: read EINVAL at    exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11) at Pipe.onread (net.js:569:26)
```

I also tried to write the casper js code in temp file and execute it from there but the behaviour is the same.

Permission of files are all ok but can't understand why this error appears.

Need some hel thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hi fixed the error putting in my php file these 2 lines:

```
putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
putenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH");
```

thanks to everyone, hope thi